# How to Stick the Toolbar to the status bar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I have updated to the new Android Studio 4.1
I am dragging a toolbar down but it is always maintaining a gap from all margins. I have not added any margins still it is happening.
see this!
[I want to make it look like this ][1] but it is happening [like this][2]

this toolbar is not sticking to the status bar,

and here is my toolbar code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="15dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you reupload your pictures so we can see the current effects and the desired effects?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have `padding = "15dp"`. You can change your code like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: hei i did but still it is not sticking to the right and left

Comment: You can also remove `paddingStart` and `paddingEnd`

Comment: actually i am new to prog can u write the code 
please

Comment: Edited my answer check it again.

Answer (score 0):

`android:padding="15dp"`-> `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes